# Running from Cron Python/ Google API will not accept stored Credentials file but from command line it will

Tags: python, cron, token, credentials, google-api-python-client

So I had what I thought was a functioning Python script which would access a stored Google Oauth Credentials file.

When I run:

```
source /METRICS/VIRTUALENVS/google/venv/bin/activate; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib'; /METRICS/GOOGLESTATS/get_report_2.py
```

it works famously.

In the python there is a block which check the credentials from a stored file:

```
#get google storage object
storage = Storage('cred_storage.txt')
credentials = storage.get()

#check if credentials are valid If not send to web page for new key.
if not credentials:
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
    storage.put(credentials)
    mysendmail('Re authentication of credentials necessary')
    exit()
```

All is good however if I run the same thing from my local user crontab the credentials fail as if the Credentials file is unreadable.

I'm stumped as to why the difference from running the command from CRON vs the command line.

Just for information I get the "go to URL" message back when the credentials fail to be read.

My permissions on the credentials file is 0755 with the owner being the user of the local crontab.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok this was an ID-10-T problem. 
Forgot to set the working directory when moving from command line to cron.

duh!

onward and upward

Comment: Thanks for the help @BostonMacOSX, that was my problem too.